# NullpointerException when findFragmentById

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an **Activity** which hosts a **Fragment**.

The **Activity** layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.my.ContentFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Java code of **Activity**:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class ContentActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //data from  previous Activity
            Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

            Fragment contentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);

            //Pass data to fragment
            /*NullpointerException, contentFragment is null!*/
            contentFragment.setArguments(data);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
...   
}
```

I try to find the fragment in `onCreate()` of Activity, and then pass some data to it. But when I `findFragmentById(...)`, I got **NullpointerException**, Why?

Comment: Too many mistakes in your codes, please refer to `Fragment` docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform a `findFragmentById` before adding the fragment to your activity. When you make a `setContentView` the `Actvitiy` inflates the layout and adds its views to the current window. In the case of having a `Fragment` in this layout, it is added with the given Id or Tag provided in the xml to the `FragmentManager`. Only in this moment you can find it there. So what you have to do is move the `findFragmentById` below the `setContentView`.

Answer (score 1):

You should move

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

before

```
  Fragment contentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
```

You got **NPE** because `findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content)` failed to find **fragment** with id `fragment_content`.

Comment: @user842225 if this solution is not working then why should you accept the answer.