# Android findFragmentById returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this problem when working on communicating from the main activity to fragment. The Monitor keeps saying:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.mick.myApplication.FragmentCal.readfiles(java.util.LinkedList)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.mick.myApplication.main.onCreate(main.java:101)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

This is the code for fragment transaction and sending the message:

```
    fragmentinfo = new FragmentInfo();
    fragmentcal = new FragmentCal();
    fragmentrep = new FragmentRep();
    fragmentdicn = new FragmentDicn();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (!fragmentcal.isAdded()) {
        if (currentFragment == null) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragmentcal).commit();
        } else {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(currentFragment).add(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragmentcal).commit();
        }
        FragmentCal fragmentCal = (FragmentCal) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentlayout);
        fragmentCal.readfiles(nameList);
    } else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(currentFragment).show(fragmentcal).commit();
    }
    currentFragment = fragmentcal;
```

And for that, I import android.support.v4.app.Fragment for all activities and fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform a findFragmentById before adding the fragment to your activity. When you make a setContentView the Activity inflates the layout and adds its views to the current window. In the case of having a Fragment in this layout, it is added with the given Id or Tag provided in the xml to the FragmentManager. Only in this moment you can find it there. So what you have to do is move the findFragmentById below the setContentView.

Source: [NullpointerException when findFragmentById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193729/nullpointerexception-when-findfragmentbyid)

Hope it helps! Good luck!